# Задали написать программу , которая выводит симметричные числа в интервале n....m

Tags: c++, python

Программа должна быть написана как и в С++, как и в PYTHON .
Программа должна вывести те симметричные числа, которые умножая друг на друга, получается симметричное число! На С++ я уже написал, но начав на PYTHOn, зашел в тупик

Программа на C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include "lvfriendly.h"

using namespace std;

bool sim(int sk)
{
    int sk2=sk, rez=0, cip;

    do
     {
         cip = sk2 % 10;
         rez = (rez * 10) + cip;
         sk2 = sk2 / 10;
     } while (sk2 != 0);
     if(sk==rez) return true;
    else return false;
}
int main()
{
    int ok;
    int n, m;

    cout << " Найдем симметричные числа в интервале [n...m] " << endl;
    do{
    bool rez=true;
    cout << "Введите n" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Введите m" << endl;
    cin >> m;
    cout << "Симметричные числа:" << endl;
    for(int i=n;i<=m;i++)
    {
        if(sim(i*i)==true) {
        cout << i << "*" << i << "=" << i*i << endl;
        rez=false; }
    }
    if(rez) cout << "Нет результата" << endl;
       cout << "Продолжить (1) , закончить (0)?" << endl;
        cin >> ok;
        }while(ok==1);
return 0;
}
```

Начало в Python.

```
bool sim(sk):
    sk2=int(sk2)
    sk=int(sk)
    rez=int(rez)
    cip=int(cip)
    sk2=sk2
    rez=0
    while (sk2 != 0):
        cip = sk2 % 10
        rez = (rez * 10) + cip
        sk2 = sk2 / 10
        (sk2 != 0)
    if sk==rez:  return true
    else: return false

print("Найдем симметричные числа в интервале [n...m]")
ok = 1
while ok == 1:
    bool rez=true
    n = input(" Введите n ")
    n = int(n)
    m = input ("Введите m ")
    m = int(m)
```

Comment: было бы здорово если бы вы добавили в вопрос описание того что делает программа на c++, а так же добавили ваши попытки решить задачу. Если вы не сделаете этого то, с высокой вероятностью, ваш вопрос закроют как "учебное задание" без попытки решить его.

Comment: всё, теперь вопрос составлен подробно

Comment: да, теперь вопрос норм

Comment: Только учтите, произведение `i * i` для **i > 46340** (совсем не больше ведь число (?!!!)) **в тип**  ***int*** **уже не влезает....**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот что у меня получилось:

```
def symmetric_numbers():
    print('Найдем все симметричные числа в интервале [n...m]')
    n, m, s = int(input('Введите n\n')), int(input('Введите m\n')), False
    # заводим необходимые переменные (через запятую, в python это называвется
    # множественное присваивание, не знаю, есть ли такое в плюсах
    print('Симметричные числа:')
    for i in range(n, m+1):
        if str(i) == str(i)[::-1] and str(i*i) == str(i*i)[::-1]:
            print(str(i) + '*' + str(i) + '=' + str(i*i))
            s = True
        # перебираем в цикле все числа интервала, если находятся подходящие нам,
        # выводим на печать и меняем значение переменной s на True
    if not s:
        print('Нет результата')
        # если таких чисел не найдено, s остается False, печатаем соответств. строку
    a = input('Продолжить (1), закончить(0)?\n')
    if a == '1':
        return symmetric_numbers()
        # если пользователь вводит единицу - рекурсивно вызываем функцию
    return


symmetric_numbers()
```

Comment: Я только немного не понимаю такой код, если не трудно, можешь добавить комментарии ?

Comment: @Halfpizods сначала просит ввести интервал где их искать, потом в цикле идет в интервале, первая проверка смотрит, если число само по себе симметричное, а потом смотрит, совпадает ли квадрат этого числа с его отображением и если да то выводит, потом спрашивает, продолжить программу? если да то рекурсивно вызывает ее, если нет выводит None, вот и все

Comment: @Halfpizods "Программа должна вывести те симметричные числа, которые умножая друг на друга, получается симметричное число!" этой формулировкой вы ввели в заблуждение, так как для "умножая друг на друга" если термин "квадрат", в будущем будьте точнее, и удачи!

Comment: @Halfpizods изменил немного код, чтоб полностью удовлетворял условию, также добавил пару комментариев, впрочем, пользователь выше всё правильно объяснил. Для проверки чисел на симметричность привожу их к типу строка и использую слайсы

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в С++ в том, что вы не проверяете симетричность самого числа `(i)`.

Поправте:

```
if(sim(i) && sim(i*i))
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).